# animated gif freezes when url is changed

Tags: javascript, css, redirect, animated-gif

I want to show an animated gif when the user searches a term and the page is redirected to the results page. The problem is that the animated gif freezes while the redirection happens. Is there a workaround for this? Maybe css3 animations instead of an animated gif?

Thanks.

Comment: What browser does this happen on?

Comment: It is happening to me in Firefox 15.0.1

Answer (score 0):

A hack to get around this is to set the image to "reload" every few milliseconds. This gives the effect that the gif is still animating.

```
setTimeout('document.images["myImageId"].src="../images/ajax-loader.gif"', 200);
```